# Python: Attribute Error When Passing Method as Function Argument

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, functional-programming

I was sure that there'd be an answer to this question somewhere on stack overflow, but I haven't been able to find one; most of them are in regards to passing functions, and not methods, as arguments to functions.

I'm currently working with Python 2.7.5 and I'm trying to define a function like this:

```
def func(object, method):
    object.method()
```

that when called like so:

```
some_object_instance = SomeObject()
func(some_object_instance, SomeObject.some_object_method)
```

using a class defined like this:

```
class SomeObject:
    def some_object_method(self):
        # do something
```

is basically equivalent to doing this:

```
some_object_instance.some_object_method()
```

I, however, keep getting an attribute error--something along the lines of

```
'SomeObject' has no attribute 'method'
```

I was under the impression that I could legally pass methods as arguments and have them evaluate correctly when used in the aforementioned manner.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way method calling works. The `foo.bar` syntax looks for a method *named* `bar` on the `foo` object. If you already have the method, just call it:

```
def func(object, method):
    method(object)

func(some_object_instance, SomeObject.some_object_method)
```

`SomeObject.some_object_method` is what's called an "unbound method": it's a method object without a `self` bound into it, so you have to explicitly pass the `self` to it.

This might make more sense with a concrete example:

```
>>> s = 'ABC'
>>> s_lower = s.lower # bound method
>>> s_lower()
'abc'
>>> str_lower = str.lower # unbound method
>>> str_lower(s)
'abc'
```

---

By comparison, `some_object_instance.some_object_method` is a "bound method", you can just call it as-is, and `some_object_instance` is already "bound in" as the `self` argument:

```
def func2(method):
    method()
func2(some_object_instance.some_object_method)
```

---

Unbound methods aren't explained in detail the tutorial; they're covered in the section on [bound methods](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects). So you have to go to the reference manual for documentation (in [standard type hierarchy] (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), way down in the subsection "User-defined methods"), which can be a little bit daunting for novices.

---

Personally, I didn't really get this until I learned how it worked under the covers. About a year ago, I wrote a blog post [How methods work](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) to try to explain it to someone else (but in Python 3.x terms, which is slightly different); it may help. To *really* get it, you have to get through the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which may take a few read-throughs and a lot of playing around in the interactive interpreter before it really clicks, but hopefully you can understand the basic concepts behind methods before getting to that point.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the difference between calling a bound method vs. an unbound method.  It worked, but I feel I should look into this a bit more.  Thanks!

Comment: @austin_sherron: Personally, I didn't really get this until I learned how it worked under the covers. About a year ago, I wrote a blog post [How methods work](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) to try to explain it to someone else (but in Python 3.x terms, which is slightly different); it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing an unbound method to the function, you need to call it as:

```
method(object)
```

Or better pass the name of the method as string and then use `getattr`:

```
getattr(object, method)()
```

Comment: Why is passing it by name instead of normally "better"?

Comment: @abarnert Because in that case we are directly dealing with the instance's method. In first case we'll have to make sure that we pass the exact same class of the instance, passing a base class's unbound method won't work.

Comment: If you want to call the object's actual class's method, you can do that; if you want to call a base class's method, you can do that too. They're both legal, it's just a matter of which you want. If you want to make sure you call `object`'s own `method`, you pass a bound method, not an unbound method plus an object _or_ a string plus an object.